# Docker vs. Shared windows folders

Tags: docker, smb, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to access a remotely shared folder from within a docker container on Docker for Windows.

While inside the container running `dir \\target\share` produces "The network path was not found.". The target can be pinged from inside the container and from the host system the share is accessible.

The image used is `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk` and I'm running it with just the `-it` option for testing.

What am I missing to get this to work?

Comment: Sound like a *file permission* problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SMB protocol works with hosts in the same LAN. A docker container, by default, has a virtual network interface behind a NAT, so the container is no longer in the same LAN. This is why you can ping the target, but you can't access the shared folder.

The easier solution is to add the option `--network host` to the `docker run` command.
In this way the container has access to the same network interfaces as the host and no virtual interface is created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to mount a folder/network share in the container

Create docker volume on the host:

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
    foo
```

Mount the volume on container:

```
$ docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=foo,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

More examples [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options)

Comment: While this would solve the problem I'm more interested as to why I can't access them from the container.